# Remove .AspNet prefix in cookie name

Tags: c#, authentication, cookies, owin

When using the OWIN Cookie authentication middleware, you can partially control the name of the cookie by changing the `AuthenticationType` in the properties, f.e.:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Test",
        //...
    });
```

Above will result in a cookie named *.AspNet.Test*. Is there any way to get rid of that *.AspNet.* prefix because we believe it reveals valuable information about the stack we're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the [`CookieName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiename(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieName) property. The docs say:

> Determines the cookie name used to persist the identity. The default value is ".AspNet.Cookies". This value should be changed if you change the name of the AuthenticationType, especially if your system uses the cookie authentication middleware multiple times.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
    {
        AuthenticationType = "Test",
        CookieName = "YourNameGoesHere",
        //...
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If a custom cookie name is not set in **CookieName** property, it is derived internally based on the authentication type string in **AuthenticationType** property and hardcoded prefix `".AspNet."`

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Options.CookieName))
{
    Options.CookieName = ".AspNet." + Options.AuthenticationType;
}
```